# Compare two string char by char in python and get unmatched character

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

I am stuck at a problem where I have two string of different length, one string is the subset of the first one.

str1='usay'

str2='usy'

I need to match both of these string in a way that in return I get index of 's' and the letter 'a', as I need to go to the index of character 's' and add an 'a' after it to match both string. How will i go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want the strings to match, why don't you just set str2 = str1? Maybe it is that easy, but maybe not.

Otherwise, you can loop over the characters in each string and check when each of them match. When you find that they don't match, you can set string 2 to add in that character like this:

```
str1 = 'usay'
str2 = 'usy'

for n in range(0,int(len(str1))):
    if str1[n] == str2[n]: print(f'letter {n} is same!')
    if str1[n] != str2[n]:
        str2 = str2[:n] + str1[n] + str2[n:] #This takes all the characters before our 
                                             #difference shows, adds the difference character,
                                             #and then adds the characters after the difference
    
print(f'str1 is {str1}')
print(f'str2 is {str2}')
```

Running this gave me the following:

```
letter 0 is same!
letter 1 is same!
letter 3 is same!
str1 is usay
str2 is usay
```

This code assumes that str1 has more characters. I think it'll work just fine if there are multiple differences (like if `str2 = uy` instead of `usy`).